# Placing elements of a nested array into a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, web-crawler

Here is the array I am working with:

```
[["5103", "2593", "1289796841"], ["1541", "99", "65990390"], ["934", "99", "73230517"], ["3057", "99", "62377700"], ["1410", "99", "81193882"], ["1232", "99", "50959566"], ["341", "99", "31225295"], ["2303", "99", "46585590"], ["91", "99", "200000000"], ["2259", "99", "32250727"], ["692", "99", "40608716"], ["4397", "99", "23545788"], ["2372", "99", "30486082"], ["408", "99", "33064494"], ["136", "99", "54937860"], ["2412", "99", "23192056"], ["858", "99", "30378477"], ["1088", "99", "21174680"], ["174", "99", "76296917"], ["477", "99", "50883493"], ["2578", "99", "24367856"], ["603", "99", "34401457"], ["1556", "99", "24433483"], ["1106", "99", "22180782"], ["1365", "99", "23373048"], ["4889", "120", "121954995"], ["10967", "97", "10702990"], ["-1", "-1"], ["-1", "-1"], ["9462", "3985121"], ["-1", "-1"], ["-1", "-1"], ["25914", "1608"], ["17184", "1538"], ["19936", "1519"], ["33498", "1651"], ["-1", "-1"], ["2589", "401"], ["14280", "1262"], ["-1", "-1"], ["-1", "-1"], ["-1", "-1"], ["32068", "378140"], ["-1", "-1"], ["-1", "-1"], ["-1", "-1"]]
```

This is a large array with many smaller arrays inside of it. The numbers of each small array represent rank, then level, then experience.

Here is another array containing the labels for each of those numbers:

```
@skills = %w(overall, attack, defence, strength, constitution, ranged, prayer, magic, cooking, woodcutting, fletching, fishing, firemaking, crafting, smithing, mining, herblore, agility, thieving, slayer, farming, runecrafting, hunter, construction, summoning, dungeoneering, divination)
```

Here is the table I am trying to create:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Skill</th>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Experience</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
  </tr>
  <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= skill.chomp(',').capitalize %></td>
    </tr>

  <% end %>

</table>
```

I have gotten as far as to place the name of each skill on its own row of the table. What I need to do now is place the level, rank, and experience of each skill next to the name of the skill in the table.

Is there a way to iterate through each element in position x of each sub-array? So that each first number in each small array is in one column?

**EDIT**

Here's what I have now:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Skill</th>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Experience</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
  </tr>
  <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= skill.chomp(',').capitalize %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

  <% @skills.each_with_index do |skill, i| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= @stats[i][0] %></td>
        <td><%= @stats[i][1] %></td>
        <td><%= @stats[i][2] %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>
```

Here is what the output looks like on the page:

[image]

That whole bottom table needs to be propped up to the right of the one on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Skill</th>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Experience</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
  </tr>
  <% @skills.each_with_index do |skill, i| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= skill.chomp(',').capitalize %></td>
      <td><%= @stats[i][0] %></td>
      <td><%= @stats[i][1] %></td>
      <td><%= @stats[i][2] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Alternatively:

```
  <% @skills.each_with_index do |skill, i| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= skill.chomp(',').capitalize %></td>
      <%= @stats[i].map{ |s| "<td>#{s}</td>" }.join %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

BTW: you can drop the commas in `%w()` literal and remove `chomp(',')` part.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe you missed what I'm trying to accomplish. My work is done with the `@skills` array. I am trying to work with the `@stats` array, such that, in the table, "Overall" is next to "5103",  "2593", and "1289796841". Then, in the next row, "Attack" should be next to "1541", "99", and "65990390".

Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated my answer but the I guess the idea stays the same. You'll get what you want with this.

Comment: Great! This worked! I've accepted your answer. One last thing, though. For some reason, the data is appearing in its own separate table. I'll update the original post to show you what it looks like. How do I get it to be one cohesive table.

Comment: I forgot about closing `</td>`. Is that the case?

Comment: Nah. I picked up on that and closed them myself. Original question is updated.

Comment: Oh, it's because you've added the snippet instead of replacing. Updated to picture the whole piece.